# Fetch IPs and Port from text

Tags: bash, awk

From this file, with awk, I would like to retrieve, all pairs of IPs:Port except if it's from swaziland

```
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>17m 19s ago</td>
                <td><script>                            document.write('93.90.232.113')</script></td>
                <td><script>                            document.write('18297')</script></td>
                <td><a href="/sockslist/country/?c=swaziland ">swaziland </a></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="center">SOCK4/5</td>
                <td class="center"><span class=blue>7</span>/<span class=red>0</span</td>
                <td class="center fast">68ms</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>20m 44s ago</td>
                <td><script>                            document.write('209.61.226.80')</script></td>
                <td><script>                            document.write('443')</script></td>
                <td><a href="/sockslist/country/?c=Wonderfullland">Wonderfullland</a></td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="center">SOCK4</td>
                <td class="center"><span class=blue>205</span>/<span class=red>0</span</td>
                <td class="center fast">127ms</td>
```

So the output here should be:

209.61.226.80:443

I can fetch ips, with the following:

```
    #! /usr/bin/awk -f

    match ($0,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/)
      { 
          ip = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
          print ip;
      }
```

with this code, I got something like (why twice...?):

...[...]

93.90.232.113

[...a lot of blank between each output...]

[...]  ('209.61.226.80') [...]

209.61.226.80

using grep, it works fine, but I dont know how to fetch the corresponding ports (and there is still the country filter issue):

`grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" <file>`

regarding the country filter, using "/country/" is not good because the word appears somewhere else, it should be something like: /try/?c=/ but it does not work for me.

Any idea?

Thank you very much folks !
strong text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below combined awk,grep,paste command,

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ RS="<tr>"} /swaziland/{next}1' file | grep -oP "(?<=document\.write\(\')[^']*" | paste -d: - -
209.61.226.80:443
```

By setting the RS(Record seperator) to `<tr>`, awk splits the whole file into  records based on the occurence of 
 tag . From the records, it skips the record if it contains `swaziland` and it print the another record.

`grep -oP "(?<=document\.write\(\')[^']*"`

Positive lookahead is used to match the string which was just after `document.write('` upto the next `'` character.

Now it prints the output in two seperate lines.

`paste -d: - -` helps to combine the result into a single line delimited by `:`

Comment: You should not that this needs  `gnu awk` doe to multiple characters in  `RS`

Comment: I pray to the God for OP must have a gnu version of awk :-)

Comment: @AvinashRaj So you hope he's not using the default awk on OS X! Actually, multiple characters in RS is a common extension.

Comment: OSX? Where he mentioned.

Comment: Jotne you also used tr tag as record seperator.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it with `gnu awk`

```
awk 'NR>1 && !/swaziland/ {print $2":"$4}' FS="'" RS="<tr>" file
209.61.226.80:443
```

By setting `RS="<tr>"` `awk` will devide data into section
Then `NR>1 && !/swaziland/` tells `awk` to ignore first section and ignore section with `swaziland`
By setting `FS="'"` you can easely get your data in field `2` and `4`

Comment: +1 This is pretty good. The `NR>1` may need to be adjusted for the actual file, though.

Comment: @ooga I think `NR>1` needs to be there in all files, since it will if not, fetch the data above first hits of `<tr>` and all section starts with `<tr>`

Comment: I didn't say it wouldn't need to be there, but depending on the actual file contents it may need to be a higher number. (Who knows how many `<tr>` blocks need to be skipped?)

Comment: @ooga You are telling that all IP should be printed except for the `swaziland`, so my solution will give you this from the data give.  But you may do like this to make sure no other data is coming out:  `NR>1 && !/swaziland/ && /document.write/`.  It will then only get blocks with `document.write` and not `swaziland`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
awk -F\' '/[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3}/{ip=$2; getline; port=$2; getline; if (!/swaziland/) print ip":"port}' file
```

Comment: `getline` should be avoided if possible.  It has so many pitfalls, that you easely can get wrong result.

Comment: @Jotne Can you be more specific about the pitfalls?

Comment: Read this http://awk.info/?tip/getline , and if you then are 100% sure what all means, its ok to use it :)

Comment: @Jotne Good reference, but obviously none of those pitfalls apply in this case.

Comment: Jotne, your solution is almost perfect, but the output still shows a chunk of useless stuff with the actual file. 
Avinash, your solution is cool. please could you specify why [^']*  -I could do it with .*?(?=\') :
awk 'BEGIN{ RS="<tr>"} /swaziland/{next}1' sockslist | grep -oP "(?<=document\.write\(\').*?(?=\')" | paste -d: - -
Third and last, but not least, the ooga solution is pretty straighforward as well and works smoothly
Thank you so much guys !

Comment: @user2945546 If this is the answer you like best you should select it as your chosen answer.